# Distinct count of multiple fields using mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, distinct

I'm trying to count distinct values of multiple fields By one MongoDB Aggregation query.

So here's my data:

```
{
    "car_type": "suv",
    "color": "red",
    "num_doors": 4
},
{
    "car_type": "hatchback",
    "color": "blue",
    "num_doors": 4
},
{
    "car_type": "wagon",
    "color": "red",
    "num_doors": 4
}
```

I want a distinct count of each field:

```
distinct_count_car_type=3
distinct_count_color=2
distinct_count_num_doors=1
```

I was able to group multiple fields and then do a distinct count but it could only give me a count on the first field. Not all of them.
And also it's a large set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the power of ... `$objectToArray`!

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT"}}}
  ,{$unwind: "$x"}
  ,{$match: {"x.k": {$ne: "_id"}}}
  ,{$group: {_id: "$x.k", y: {$addToSet: "$x.v"}}}
  ,{$addFields: {size: {"$size":"$y"}} }
                    ]);
```

This will yield:

```
{ "_id" : "num_doors", "y" : [ 4 ], "size" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "color", "y" : [ "blue", "red" ], "size" : 2 }
{
    "_id" : "car_type",
    "y" : [
        "wagon",
        "hatchback",
        "suv"
    ],
    "size" : 3
}
```

You can `$project`or `$addFields`as you see fit to include or exclude the set of unique values or the size.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using mongodb 3.2 and $objectToArray I think according to manual was introduced in 3.4.

Comment: Correct.    I'd recommend the upgrade to 3.4.4.

Comment: So I upgraded & tried your solution.The issue I now have is those dynamic fields that I wanted to do a distinct count on are actually in an array because they where from a $lookup from another collection. The collection at the top of the question is in an array on my results because of a $lookup. So when I try to do an $objectToArray on the field I get "$objectToArray requires a document input, found: array". And I tried $arrayToObject first to maybe be able to then call $objectToArray on it and I get "$arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'key' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:5".

Comment: At a high level I see $map in concert with $objectToArray achieving your goal.   Perhaps you should repost another question with this high level change?

Comment: I posted the new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591045/need-a-distinct-count-on-multiple-fields-that-were-joined-from-another-collectio

Comment: All I had to do was add $unwind before your $project and it works. Someone commented about that in the other question. I gave you the answer btw!

Answer (score 5):

Running the following aggregate pipeline should give you the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "distinct_car_types": { "$addToSet": "$car_type" },
            "distinct_colors": { "$addToSet": "$color" },
            "distinct_num_doors": { "$addToSet": "$num_doors" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "distinct_count_car_type": { "$size": "$distinct_car_types" },
            "distinct_count_color": { "$size": "$distinct_colors" },
            "distinct_count_num_doors": { "$size": "$distinct_num_doors" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: nice, and you can also add `_id: 0` in projection ;).

Comment: This works. Thanks! It slows down a little but not too much. I might need to make a new question but what if those objects consisted of an dynamic number of fields(meaning I wouldn't be able to hard code the field name ahead of time). Is there a way to get distinct counts on any number of fields in my map? How might I do this?

Comment: @Deckard see below.