# Need a distinct count on multiple fields that were joined from another collection using mongodb aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, distinct

I'm trying to use a mongodb aggregation query to join($lookup) two collections and then distinct count all the unique values in the joined array.

So my two collections look like this:
events-

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "event1",
    "objectsIds" : [ "1", "2", "3" ],
}
```

Objects

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "object1",
    "metaDataMap" : { 
                         "SOURCE" : ["ABC", "DEF"],
                         "DESTINATION" : ["XYZ", "PDQ"],
                         "TYPE" : []
                    }
},
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "name" : "object2",
    "metaDataMap" : { 
                         "SOURCE" : ["RST", "LNE"],
                         "TYPE" : ["text"]
                    }
},
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "name" : "object3",
    "metaDataMap" : { 
                         "SOURCE" : ["NOP"],
                         "DESTINATION" : ["PHI", "NYC"],
                         "TYPE" : ["video"]
                    }
}
```

What I want to come out is when I do a $match on event _id=1 I want to join the metaDataMap and then distinct count all the keys like this:
Counts for event _id=1

```
SOURCE : 5
DESTINATION: 4
TYPE: 2
```

What I have so far is this:

```
db.events.aggregate([
 {$match: {"_id" : id}}
,{$lookup: {"from" : "objects",
            "localField" : "objectsIds",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "objectResults"}}
,{$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$objectResults.metaDataMap"}}}
,{$unwind: "$x"}
,{$match: {"x.k": {$ne: "_id"}}}
,{$group: {_id: "$x.k", y: {$addToSet: "$x.v"}}}
,{$addFields: {size: {"$size":"$y"}} }
]);
```

This fails because $objectResults.metaDataMap is not an object it's an array. Any suggestions on how to solve this or a different way to do what I want to do? 
Also I don't necessarily know what fields(keys) are in the metaDataMap array. And I don't want to count or include fields that might or might not exist in the Map.

Comment: why don't you unwind onjectResults before project?

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: happy to help..

Comment: ?   Are you sure you don't have an array of arrays as a result of the addToSet?   x.v is an array so calling addToSet won't dedupe the contents of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  I tested it on your input set and deliberately added some dupe values like `NYC`showing up in more than one `DESTINATION`to ensure it got de-duped (i.e. distinct count as asked for).
For fun, comment out all the stages, then top down UNcomment it out to see the effect of each stage of the pipeline.

```
var id = "1";

c=db.foo.aggregate([
// Find a thing:
{$match: {"_id" : id}}

// Do the lookup into the objects collection:
,{$lookup: {"from" : "foo2",
            "localField" : "objectsIds",
            "foreignField" : "_id",
            "as" : "objectResults"}}

// OK, so we've got a bunch of extra material now.  Let's
// get down to just the metaDataMap:
,{$project: {x: "$objectResults.metaDataMap"}}
,{$unwind: "$x"}
,{$project: {"_id":0}}

// Use $objectToArray to get all the field names dynamically:
// Replace the old x with new x (don't need the old one):
,{$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$x"}}}
,{$unwind: "$x"}

// Collect unique field names.  Interesting note: the values
// here are ARRAYS, not scalars, so $push is creating an
// array of arrays:
,{$group: {_id: "$x.k", tmp: {$push: "$x.v"}}}

// Almost there!  We have to turn the array of array (of string)
// into a single array which we'll subsequently dedupe.  We will
// overwrite the old tmp with a new one, too:
,{$addFields: {tmp: {$reduce:{
    input: "$tmp",
    initialValue:[],
    in:{$concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this"]}
        }}
    }}

// Now just unwind and regroup using the addToSet operator
// to dedupe the list:
,{$unwind: "$tmp"}
,{$group: {_id: "$_id", uniqueVals: {$addToSet: "$tmp"}}}

// Add size for good measure:
,{$addFields: {size: {"$size":"$uniqueVals"}} }
          ]);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "exceeded maximum document size" when I try it on a large dataset. What the best/fastest way to get around the max doc size?

Comment: ?    Is this with {$match: {"_id" : id}} in place?    And how many objects are you looking up?    There's an X*Y thing going on somewhere here to expand the pipeline into 16MB per document.

Comment: Yes I have the match id in there. It varied how many I look up but it fails after 25,000 objects in the lookup step. Also I read in the 3.4 docs that the pipeline is restricted by the 16Mb size only for the returning result and not during the pipeline process? So why I'm I getting an error if I the results are not exceeding the limit?

Comment: I made a new post with my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692892/mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-size-and-speed-issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate required result using following query.

```
db.events.aggregate(
   [  
      {$match: {"_id" : id}} ,
      {$lookup: {
          "from" : "objects",
          "localField" : "objectsIds",
          "foreignField" : "_id",
          "as" : "objectResults"
      }},
      {$unwind: "$objectResults"},
      {$project:{"A":"$objectResults.metaDataMap"}},
      {$unwind: {path: "$A.SOURCE", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
      {$unwind:{ path: "$A.DESTINATION", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
      {$unwind:{ path: "$A.TYPE", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
      {$group:{"_id":"$_id","SOURCE":{$addToSet:"$A.SOURCE"},"DESTINATION":{$addToSet:"$A.DESTINATION"},"TYPE":{$addToSet:"$A.TYPE"}}},
      {$addFields: {"SOURCE":{$size:"$SOURCE"},"DESTINATION":{$size:"$DESTINATION"},"TYPE":{$size:"$TYPE"}}},
      {$project:{"_id":0}}]
).pretty()
```

Updated query for dynamic fields.

```
db.events.aggregate([  
{
$match: {"_id" : id}} ,
{$lookup: {"from" : "objects","localField" : "objectsIds","foreignField" : "_id","as" : "objectResults"}},
{$unwind: "$objectResults"},
{$project:{"A":"$objectResults.metaDataMap"}},
{$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$A"}}},
{$unwind: "$x"},
{$match: {"x.k": {$ne: "_id"}}},
{$unwind:"$x.v"},
{$group: {_id: "$x.k", y: {$addToSet: "$x.v"}}},
{$project:{"size":{$size:"$y"}}}]
).pretty()
```

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that I don't necessarily know what fields(keys) are in the metaDataMap array. And I don't want to count or include fields that might or might not exist in the Map.