# Mongodb aggregation pipeline size and speed issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use a mongodb aggregation query to join($lookup) two collections and then distinct count all the unique values in the joined array. *Note: I don't necessarily know what fields(keys) are in the metaDataMap array. And I don't want to count or include fields that might or might not exist in the Map. So that's why the aggregation query looks like it does.

So my two collections look like this: events-

```
{
"_id" : "1",
"name" : "event1",
"objectsIds" : [ "1", "2", "3" ],
}
```

Objects

```
{
"_id" : "1",
"name" : "object1",
"metaDataMap" : { 
                     "SOURCE" : ["ABC", "DEF"],
                     "DESTINATION" : ["XYZ", "PDQ"],
                     "TYPE" : []
                }
},
{
"_id" : "2",
"name" : "object2",
"metaDataMap" : { 
                     "SOURCE" : ["RST", "LNE"],
                     "TYPE" : ["text"]
                }
},
{
"_id" : "3",
"name" : "object3",
"metaDataMap" : { 
                     "SOURCE" : ["NOP"],
                     "DESTINATION" : ["PHI", "NYC"],
                     "TYPE" : ["video"]
                }
}
```

My results are

```
{
_id:"SOURCE", count:5
_id:"DESTINATION", count: 4
_id:"TYPE", count: 2
}
```

What I have so far is this:

```
db.events.aggregate([
{$match: {"_id" : id}}

,{$lookup: {"from" : "objects",
        "localField" : "objectsIds",
        "foreignField" : "_id",
        "as" : "objectResults"}}

,{$unwind: "$objectResults"} //Line 1
,{$project: {x: "$objectResults.metaDataMap"}} //Line 2


,{$unwind: "$x"}
,{$project: {"_id":0}}

,{$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$x"}}}
,{$unwind: "$x"}

,{$group: {_id: "$x.k", tmp: {$push: "$x.v"}}}

,{$addFields: {tmp: {$reduce:{
input: "$tmp",
initialValue:[],
in:{$concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this"]}
    }}
}}

,{$unwind: "$tmp"}
,{$group: {_id: "$_id", uniqueVals: {$addToSet: "$tmp"}}}

,{$addFields: {count: {"$size":"$uniqueVals"}}}
,{$project: {_id: "$_id", count: "$count"}}
]);
```

My issue is were I marked line 1&2. The above works but takes around 50 seconds for 25,000 values in the metaDataMap array fields(objectsResults.metaDataMap). So for example having a 25,000 values in object 1 metaDataMap SOURCE array. That's way to slow. My other faster way to do it was to replace line 1&2 with:

```
 ,{$project: {x: "$objectResults.metaDataMap"}} //Line 1
 ,{$unwind: "$x"} //Line 2
```

This is way faster (under 3 seconds) but can only be run on datasets that have ~10,000 items or less. Anything higher and I get a error saying "exceeds maximum document size".

Please help!

Comment: Could add a little more description around "25,000 items in various arrays"?

Comment: Just a thought. May be you can try changing your `metaDataMap` structure to `"metaDataMap" : ["k":{ "SOURCE", "v" : [  "ABC", "DEF"  ]}...]` and insert a `$map` stage after `$lookup`.  Something like `{"$project": {"data":{"$map": {"input":"$objectResults.metaDataMap","as": "resultom","in": {"$map": {"input": "$$resultom","as": "resultim","in": {"k":"$$resultim.k","v":{ "$size": "$$resultim.v"}}}}} }}}`. I believe this way you can get the size and unwinding should be quicker.

Comment: But I won't get a distinct count with the size. Will I? I need to dedupe the v values.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to alter your schema design on the `object` collection to include a `parent_id` field, you can immediately remove the first 4 stages of your pipeline (the first `$match`, `$lookup`, `$unwind`, and `$project`). This will make the concern about `Line 1` and `Line 2` disappear.

For example, a document in the `object` collection would look like:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "name": "object1",
  "metaDataMap": {
    "SOURCE": [
      "ABC",
      "DEF"
    ],
    "DESTINATION": [
      "XYZ",
      "PDQ"
    ],
    "TYPE": [ ]
  },
  "parent_id": "1"
}
```

Thus you don't need the expensive `$lookup` and `$unwind`. The first 4 stages can then be replaced with:

```
{$match: {parent_id: id}}
```

Based on this idea, I did further optimization of the pipeline, which resulted in:

```
db.objects.aggregate([
     {$match: {parent_id: id}}
    ,{$project: {metaDataMap: {$filter: {input: {$objectToArray: '$metaDataMap'}, cond: {$ne: [[], '$$this.v']}}}}}
    ,{$unwind: '$metaDataMap'}
    ,{$unwind: '$metaDataMap.v'}
    ,{$group: {_id: '$metaDataMap.k', val: {$addToSet: '$metaDataMap.v'}}}
    ,{$project: {count: {$size: '$val'}}}
])
```

This will output:

```
{ "_id": "TYPE", "count": 2 }
{ "_id": "DESTINATION", "count": 4 }
{ "_id": "SOURCE", "count": 5 }
```