# Mongodb 3.4.7 aggregation distinct count of one field after grouping

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have

```
{
"statement": {
   “activity”: {
    "definition": {
             “name”: “ACT_NAME1”
    }
    },
"actor": {
       "name": "User 2”
    }
},
"statement": {
   “activity”: {
    "definition": {
             “name”: “ACT_NAME2”
    }
    },
"actor": {
       "name": "User 1"
    }
},
"statement": {
   “activity”: {
    "definition": {
             “name”: “ACT_NAME2”
    }
    },
"actor": {
       "name": "User 1"
    }
},
"statement": {
   “activity”: {
    "definition": {
             “name”: “ACT_NAME1”
    }
    },
"actor": {
       "name": "User 1"
    }
 }
}
```

I want to group by statement.activity.definition.name and in each group calculate distinct count of actor.name. How to do this?

```
{ activity: ACT_NAME1
  unique_actor_count: 2 }

{ activity: ACT_NAME2
 unique_actor_count: 1 }
```

Also I have some match condition for this and not provided here.

Comment: First of all the "I have" snippet makes no sense. It is not a valid json document. Apart from that you didn't show your attempts to at lease use $group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distinct count of multiple fields using mongodb aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471856/distinct-count-of-multiple-fields-using-mongodb-aggregation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$addToSet` to accumulate grouped items into a Set (unique elements)

```
document.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {}},
    {$group: 
         {
            _id: '$statement.activity.definition.name',
            actors: {$addToSet: '$statement.actor.name'}
         }
     },
     {$project: {
         _id: '$_id',
         actors: '$actors',
         uniqueActorsCount: {$size: '$actors'}
     }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, you saved me. Is there any way to add a key like this t output? {
  "activity_statements_users_count": [{}, {}, {} ] }

Comment: What do you mean?what does {} represent?

Comment: Ohh sry, it is our output. say:
`{
        "_id": "Save or close the hotel – what would you suggest?",
        "users": [
            "Rohit. LMS Test"
        ],
        "name": "Save or close the hotel – what would you suggest?",
        "statements_count": 1,
        "unique_users_count": 1
    }`

Comment: Right now I am getting like this: [{}, {}, {} ]. can I wrap it around a hash key ?
`{  activity_statements_users_count: {[{}, {}, {} ]}  }`

Comment: Can we use the group condition above project ? I read somewhere that group comes last.

Comment: can u try to answer this qn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152423/mongodb-3-4-7-aggregation-convert-ptms-time-to-seconds

Comment: I guess you can give a try to answer this also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188337/mongo-aggregation-convert-string-to-date-in-version-3-4-7