# Mongodb 3.4.7 Aggregation Convert ptms time to seconds

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following json:

```
{  
   "statement":{  
      "result":{  
         "duration":"PT0.552S",
         "completion":true,
         "success":false
      }
   },
   "statement":{  
      "result":{  
         "duration":"PT0.552S",
         "completion":true,
         "success":false
      }
   },
   "statement":{  
      "result":{  
         "duration":"PT0.552S",
         "completion":true,
         "success":false
      }
   }
}
```

How can I write a mongo aggregator to getting the statement -> result -> duration  time format that now in ptms  string to seconds?

I need something like:

```
    [
        1131,
        648,
        1678,
        .....
        .....
    ]
```

Here each number is the duration that is converted into seconds.

Here : http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour I can see : "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z") but how to use it for ptms time format?

I am encoding these aggregators and passing in query parameters to server to get the result. So how to use ISODate in query parameter ? How can I encode it? say like encode the following json format and pass it in GET query parameters:

```
 { 
        "$project": {
      "duration": "$ISODate('$statement.result.duration')"
        }
  }
```

Comment: What is `ptms time` and how you convert `PT0.552S` to seconds?

Comment: I am a ruby developer and usually converts that with ISODate function.
like: `ISO8601::Duration.new(statement.result["duration"])`

Comment: Here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/
I can see :
`"date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:15:39.736Z")`
but how to use it for ptms and I am encoding these aggregators and passing in query parameters to server to get the result. So how to use ISODate in query parameter ?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: IIRC, mongo does not understand the ISO 8601 duration format. You might change your schema to store the duration directly I think.

Comment: Is there a way by using `ISODate` function of mongo aggregation?

Comment: I think not. Because date in mongoDB represent a point in timeline, rather than a duration

Comment: can u provide me atleast to get like:
`[ 
 "PT0.552S”, 
  "PT0.552S”,  
  "PT0.552S"
]
`

Comment: Like the previous answer, but use `$push` to accummulate to array

Comment: Yes, but I have a doubt, push we can use in group stage only, and I dont want to use group by any field. So how can I use it? and group needed a mondatory _id field also to group.

Comment: Group on null which is same as no grouping. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-null)

Comment: OK, thanks, got it, but I still gets a `"_id": "null",` in output. Can I avoid it?

Comment: You can use project stage with exclusion after group stage. Soemthing like {$project:{_id:0}}