# Mongo aggregation Convert string to date in version 3.4.7

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregator function, which I am not firing in mongo console directly. I am passing this aggregator to an API as a query string. I will encode the following aggregator directly and pass to a get request as a query string.

```
[

      {
         "$limit": 500
      },

      {
            "$match": {
              "timestamp": {
                "$gte": {
                  "$dte": "2017-07-01"
                },
                "$lt": {
                  "$dte": "2020-12-31"
                }
              }
            }
      },      

      {
            "$group": {
                "_id": { "$year": "$timestamp" },
                "scores": { "$push": "$statement.result.score.scaled" },
                "duration_seconds": { "$push": "$statement.result.duration_seconds" }
             }
      },

      { 
            "$project": {
                 "scores": 1,
                 "duration_seconds": 1,
                 "statements_count": 1,
                 "semester": { 
                                "$cond": [  
                                            { 
                                                "$lte": [ 
                                                          {  
                                                            "$month": 
                                                                { 
                                                                  "$dateFromString": {
                                                                    "dateString": "$timestamp"
                                                                  }
                                                                }
                                                          }, 6
                                                        ] 
                                            }, "Jan", "July" 
                                         ]
                             }
            }  
      },

      {
            "$group": {
                "_id": { "semester": "$semester", "year": { "$year": "$timestamp" } },
                "avg_score": { "$avg": "$scores" },
                "avg_duration": { "$avg": "$duration_seconds" },
                "statements_count": { "$sum": 1 }
             }
      }
    ]
```

Here I have a statement document, it has a `timestamp` that is a ISO date but in string format. I want to group the statements by semester (if month is `1-6: Jan, 6-12: July`)

Here the problem is I am using mongo 3.4.7 and `"$dateFromString"` operator only works in above 3.6 versions. So I am getting an error.

1. So how can I group this by semester in mongo 3.4.7 version ?
2. I am facing the following issue while grouping by semester first.

   And my aggregation not works for grouping by semester. Because how can I use the semester grouping first and do the project stage? Group stage is not supporting `$cond` etc aggregator that I can use only in `project` stage.

Comment: Which of 3 options are suitable for you: upgrade; update all documents with proper date; run map-reduce?

Comment: I can't upgrade, the server is running on 3.4.
Its so difficult to update all documents because I migrated lot of data from other db with string format (I have like: `"timestamp" : "2017-03-25T05:43:12.792301Z",`)
Map - reduce I can't use because I don't have any interface apart from aggregation

Comment: Can we use map - reduce in mongo aggregation ?

Comment: Then you cannot use datetime functions and have to deal with strings - parse, extract, etc.

Comment: Could you pls help on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) operator with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) for index 1 to return month value.

```
{"semester":{
  "$cond":[
    {"$lte":[{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$split":["$timestamp","-"]},1]},"06"]},
    "Jan",
    "July"
  ]
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but the aggregation not works, because can u tell me how can I do the grouping by semester first ? I updated my answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Try `{$group:{_id:{"semester":{   "$cond":[     {"$lte":[{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$split":["$timestamp","-"]},1]},"06"]},     "Jan",     "July"   ] }}}}`

Comment: I got : `$split requires an expression that evaluates to a string as a first argument, found: date` , I think it coming as date only!, but I am getting as a string. So I will try to convert it to string and try.

Comment: At last I made it work with `$month`, because that is working inside `group -> _id`, it was not working for me in group stages outside _id. Anyway thats for the tips and I accepting the answer.

Comment: Could you help on this one pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version